# polymorphic_path for custom collection route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, polymorphic-associations, custom-routes

I have the following route definition:

```
resources :documents do
  collection do
    post :filter
  end
end
```

and the following model structure:

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :documentable, :polymorphic => true
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :documents, :as => :documentable
end
```

and controller structure:

```
class DocumentsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    # not important
  end

  def filter
    # not important
  end
end
```

I can easily in a view say:

```
polymorphic_path([@user, Document])
```

to get the path **/users/1/documents**, but I want to be able to say:

```
filter_polymorphic_path([@user, Document])
```

to get the path **/users/1/documents/filter**, unfortunately, this doesn't work.

Anyone know how I can pull this off without adding the following to my routes, for each of my *documentable* models:

```
resources :users do
  resources :documents do
    collection do
      post :filter
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`polymorphic_path([@user, Document], :action => 'filter')` gives you  `/users/:user_id/documents/filter`.

Also, `polymorphic_path([@user, Document], :action => 'filter', :sort_order => 'this-order')` gives you `/users/:user_id/documents/filter?sort_order=this-order`.

I ran into the same problem thinking you can replace the `edit` in `edit_polymorphic_path` to whatever method you want.

See: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html

Answer (score 4):

This would do it, and it reads nicely.

```
polymorphic_path([:filter, @user, Document])
```

Or these

```
polymorphic_path([:filter, @user, :documents])
polymorphic_path([:filter, @user, Document.new])
```

And with a query param

```
polymorphic_path([:filter, @user, Document], :q => 'keyword')
```

And, in a view you can also do this:

```
= link_to "Documents", [[:filter, @user, :documents], :q => 'keyword']
```