# Polymorphic_url back incorrect path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphic-associations

In my Rails application I have an `Images` class that is used by `Store` & `Maker`, I've set `Images` up as belong to a polymorphic association through `imageable` (following most of the standard docs and Railscasts), most of it works, however when I add a back button to an image I'm not sure what I'm actually meant to put in for the options:

```
polymorphic_path(@imageable.images)
```

Doesn't work: `image_image_image_image_image_path` is the resulting thrown error, and various different combinations of `([@imageable, images])` and so on haven't helped. `@imageable` definitely points to the correct class though, if I leave it as `polymorphic_path(@imageable)` it'll return to the `show` for the passed object.

I'm guessing I've misunderstood how I'm passing the objects in but I can't see where.

Edit: just to clarify, by back I mean returning to the index of images for the object.

Edit: just to expand on what I've tried, `polymorphic_url` returns the same issue. `imageable_images_path` doesn't work as it's not a `:resource` in `routes.rb`, `[@imageable, images]` returns that `images` is an undefined.

Edit: To save turning this into a giant I'll add the relevant files as gists:

- Routes.rb https://gist.github.com/nicholassmith/6239704
- Image.rb https://gist.github.com/nicholassmith/6239708
- Store.rb https://gist.github.com/nicholassmith/6239717
- The relevant `rake routes` output https://gist.github.com/nicholassmith/6239971

Comment: what do you mean by 'back button' - closing an image and going back to content or going to the previous image?

Comment: Sorry I'll clarify that, clicking back should return you to the image index.

Comment: If you want to return to image index, why not use images_path directly?

Comment: It doesn't work, `Images` are kept as a subresource in the route.

Comment: can you add your routes file?

Comment: sorry, last thing...output of rake routes

Comment: Done, I trimmed off all the routes that don't apply (other models etc).

Comment: really the last thing :p - `@imageable` is defined in a controller somewhere - can you upload that controller file, and while you're at it, the view that's giving you trouble?

Comment: `Imageable` isn't a controller, or a model. Here's the Rails documentation on it: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about [polymorphic_url](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes/polymorphic_url)

Something like `polymorphic_url(@imageable.images)` or even just `polymorphic_url(images)` might work

**EDIT**: I think maybe the problem is the `@imageable`

according to the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html):

```
# calls post_url(post)
polymorphic_url(post) # => "http://example.com/posts/1"
polymorphic_url([blog, post]) # => "http://example.com/blogs/1/posts/1"
polymorphic_url([:admin, blog, post]) # => "http://example.com/admin/blogs/1/posts/1"
polymorphic_url([user, :blog, post]) # => "http://example.com/users/1/blog/posts/1"
polymorphic_url(Comment) # => "http://example.com/comments"
```

So when you pass `polymorphic_path(@imageable)` and it gives you the relevant show page, that makes sense because passing `@imageable` is in fact passing a specific instance of `imageable` - `/stores/X/images/1` or `/stores/X/images/2`, etc.  If you want to go to the index, you don't want a specific instance of `imageable` - you want only `images`

This is untested, but try either

**`polymorphic_path(store, :images)`** / **`polymorphic_url(store, :images)`**

or

**`polymorphic_path(@imageable, :action => 'index')`**

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6205831/2128691

Comment: I've tried both `polymorphic_url` and `polymorphic_path`. I'll update the question with that information.

Comment: Kudos to you good sir, you weren't 100% there but you were pretty damn close. It's actually `polymorphic_path([@imageable, :images])`, so a combination of a few things.